# запись объекта в массив

Tags: php

```
     public static function registrationUser(User $user){
     //логика записи в массив $list
       $fp = fopen(self::USER_FILE,'w');
        foreach ($list as $item){
            fputcsv($fp,$item,';','"');
        }
        fclose($fp);
    }
```

на вход поступает объект, нужно записать в сsv файл, преобразовав объект в массив

как именно записать объект в массив?

Comment: попробуйте вот такой способ http://atoumus.github.io/php-write-read-binary-files.html

Comment: а просто (array) $user  не работает?

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно вытащить и записать все public-свойства объекта, есть [get_object_vars](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.get-object-vars.php)

Если csv не обязательно должен быть человекочитаемым, есть [serialize](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.serialize.php)